# How to create a grouped bar plot from lists of uneven length

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot groups of data which have different length of data. Do you have any idea how I can visualize a female list containing only two objects without filling up the rest of them with zeros to get the length of the male list?

This is the code, which I got so far:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, male, width, label='male')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, female, width, label='female')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make two different array for the x-positions:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7]

x_male = np.arange(len(male))
x_female = np.arange(len(female))

offset_male = np.zeros(len(male))
offset_female = np.zeros(len(female))

shorter = min(len(x_male), len(x_female))

width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

offset_male[:shorter] = width/2
offset_female[:shorter] = width/2

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x_male - offset_male, male, width, label='male')
rects2 = ax.bar(x_female + offset_female, female, width, label='female')
```

That said, this solution only works when values are missing at the end of the shorter list. For values missing within the list, it would be better to use None, or np.nan, as suggested by @desert_ranger.

Comment: Thanks @warped! Is there any way to get the G3 and G4 labels, which correspond to the male data at the middle of bars?

Comment: @Monica see my edit. May I ask if there is a particular reason why you don't want to fill the array with zeros?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to fill them up with zeros, you could assign NAN values to them -

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7,np.nan,np.nan]

x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.bar(x - width/2, male, width, label='male')
ax.bar(x + width/2, female, width, label='female')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()

fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @desert_ranger! Is there any easy way to get the G3 and G4 labels at the middle of bars?

Answer (score 0):

- Use pandas and plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8.11`, `pandas 1.3.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`**

#### Option 1

- Column data must be the same length when creating a dataframe, therefore use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) to zip lists of unequal length, which fills the missing data with a `fillvalue`.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from itertools import zip_longest

# data
labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7]

# zip lists together
data = zip_longest(male, female)

# create dataframe from data
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['male', 'female'], index=labels)

    male  female
G1     1     2.0
G2     3     7.0
G3    10     NaN
G4    20     NaN

# plot
p = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### Option 2

- Row do not need to be the same length to add to the dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4']
male = [1, 3, 10, 20]
female = [2, 7]

# create a dataframe from the lists
df = pd.DataFrame([male, female], columns=labels, index=['male', 'female'])

        G1  G2    G3    G4
male     1   3  10.0  20.0
female   2   7   NaN   NaN

# plot
p = df.plot.bar(rot=0)
```

[image]