# How to make group bars on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I am trying to plot multiple bars on the same plot on my jupyter notebook. However, due to some reason, it does not work on the notebook,but it works on a normal python editor. Here is the code that I have used.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(['A','B','C'],[72,73,88])
plt.bar(['A','B','C'],[98,77,98])
plt.show()
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

(Edit)
I am looking for somthing like this on my jupyter notebook.
[image]

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney apologies if I have framed my question in a wrong way. But it is something like the one on the picture that I have just added.

Comment: The question should be, how to make grouped bars

Comment: `df = pd.DataFrame({'boy': [72,73,88], 'girl': [98,77,98]}, index= ['A','B','C'])` and then `df.plot(kind='bar', rot=0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a grouped bar plot from lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68743418/7758804)

Comment: Thanks @TrentonMcKinney. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to have both bar plots side by side. So here you go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig,axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
axs[0].bar(['A','B','C'],[72,73,88])
axs[1].bar(['A','B','C'],[98,77,98])
plt.show()
```